# Информация по установленным принтерам

Tags: linux, администрирование

Как в linux как получить информацию о том какие принтеры установлены?

Comment: Попробуй посмотреть в CUPS.
По умолчанию находится тут: http://localhost:631/admin

Comment: lpstat -p -d Взято из [сообщества SuperUser](http://superuser.com/a/177461/53041).